# Error copying large file to diffferent drive (both ext4) "Error splicing file: Input/output"

Tags: 16.04, gnome, virtualbox, ext4, copy

This might seem like a common question, but I haven't found an answer to it here.

I'm trying to move a really large file (50GB, it's a virtual harddrive with windows 10 on it). I want to copy it from my `/home` (located on HDD) to `/vdrive` (located on SSD).

Everything is formated in **EXT4** (no fat32 or NTFS) and the `/vdrive` directory has the corresponding permissions.
The error thrown is

```
Error splicing file: Input/output
```

I've have had this problem before trying copying this type of large file from one directory to other. I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: [How do I solve error splicing files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/348888/how-do-i-solve-error-splicing-files)

Comment: I don't see any workaround or solution on that post, they talk about formatting the drive to ext4, which in my case already is. Unless I'm missing something

Comment: Hmm, can't think of anything else if you _know_ that both are in EXT4. Sorry that I couldn't help.

Comment: Did you TRIM the ssd before the copy?  Did you ever run the smartctl health report on the ssd?

Comment: trim is enabled , but I tested copying the file inside the same hardrive and I get the same error.

Comment: Are you dragging the file to copy it? Try opening the terminal app and using `cp` to copy the file. This would eliminate Nautilus as the one choking on the large file. Let me know. Cheers, Al

Comment: Yeah I've tried copying it using the terminal, same error

Comment: @FedeFavale, Could you try running a file system check using `fsck.ext4`

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit late and may not be what is wrong in your case but I encountered this issue as well and the formatting was not the issue.

Disabling auto sleep mode on my device (or perhaps some other power saving feature in your case) solved it for me.