# How to resolve error splicing files on Thunar

Tags: ubuntu-studio, thunar

I installed UbuntuStudio 18.04 and I have been trying to copy media files from my NAS with Thunar, but it fails with error splicing ...

I have tried everything on the internet, and when I installed Dolphin the copy process worked without error.

I would like to use Thunar, as Dolphin does not seem to be native to the OS (KDE).

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you share some details about your setup? Do any of the proposed solutions [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348888/how-do-i-solve-error-splicing-files) work for you?

Comment: nope I tried EXT2 EXT4 all of them.
It seems to be on Thunar 
When pasting the required files to Dolphin it works, until now 19GB has been copied. Previously it would give me an error after 1-2MB

Comment: By the way I prefer to stay on Dolphin, but under UBUNTU STUDIO the notification status does not show anything of the status of the copy job or any  job....

Comment: On Thunar 4.6.11, I'm getting the odd glitch with the same error. gvfs 1.50.2-1 on Manjaro.  I'm doing bulk copying on a USB drive.  It's as if the drive just disconnects after a long copy process. (Coping to an EXT4 file system.)