# How can I copy .DAT files from a CD to my desktop in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: vlc

I have an old CD which has some videos on it. The videos seem to be in the .DAT format. Although they automatically play back through VLC Media Player, both the terminal and the GUI are unable to copy those .DAT files from the CD to my desktop.

To those who may suggest using Isobuster through Wine, I have already tried that solution. It does not work.

I navigated to a folder on the CD in which these .DAT files were present. I tried to copy them to my Desktop, but it showed an error.

GNOME Disk Utility says the CD Drive is read only.

[image]

[image]

Comment: These seems to be related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/348888/how-do-i-solve-error-splicing-files and https://linux.die.net/man/2/splice

Comment: I have no hard drive errors.  I only faced the error in the image of your linked question.  I found my solution, anyway.  Thanks for the help, Hannu.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help, everybody. I was exploring a few more forums on my own, and came across [this question on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335101/copy-files-from-vcd-without-conversion-to-mpeg). I was able to get all my videos working.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/604805/165104) by [Xavras Wyzryn](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/141192/xavras-wyzryn) was the one that helped me.

It uses `vcdxrip`. Here are the key steps.

> 1. Install it with `apt-get install vcdimager`
> 2. Insert the VCD into the drive. It does not need to be mounted.
> 3. Open the terminal and navigate to the directory on your hard drive where you want the files from the VCD.
> 4. Run `vcdxrip -vpC`

Note that if the `vcdxrip -vpC` command is run in a new terminal, the necessary files will be copied in .MPG format to the Home directory.